# Error page not found manipulation URL with slug in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting error page not found when I implementation URL using slug.

This is code in controller

```
function view($slug)
{
    $this->data['halaman_item'] = $this->mhalaman->get_profil($slug);

    if (empty($this->data['halaman_item'])) {
        show_404();
    }

    $this->data['title'] = $this->data['halaman_item']['judul'];            $this->data['orang'] = $this->mlogin->dataPengguna($this->session->userdata('username'));
    $this->data['contents'] = $this->load->view('mahasiswa/profil/sejarah', $this->data, true);
    $this->load->view('template/wrapper/mahasiswa/wrapper_content',$this->data);
}
```

Model

```
function get_profil($slug = FALSE)
{
    if ($slug === FALSE)
    {
        $query = $this->db->get($this->tbl_halaman);
        return $query->result_array();
    }

    $query = $this->db->get_where($this->tbl_halaman, array('slug'=>$slug));
    return $query->row_array();
}
```

Route

```
$route['profil/view'] = "profil/view";
$route['profil/(:any)'] = "profil/view/$1";
$route['profil'] = "profil";
```

When I run this link `tkd/index.php/mahasiswa/profil/sejarah` is 404 page is not found. may be you know where is the probelm.

Help me what to do. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, without knowing how much of the rest of your app works...the first obvious thing is making sure `$this->data['halaman_item']` actually has data in it...because if not, it's calling `show_404` before anything happens.